# how to get HTML DOM path by text content?

Tags: java, html

a HTML file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <p id="tID">content</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i has a String == `"content"`,

i want to use `"content"` get HTML DOM path:

```
html body div.main p#tID
```

chrome developer tools has this feature(Elements tag,bottom bar), i want to know how to do it in java?

thanks for your help :)

Comment: you mean java, or javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have fun :)

**JAVA CODE**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties;
import org.htmlcleaner.DomSerializer;
import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;



public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // read and clean document
            TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(new File("test.xml"));
            Document document = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);

            // use XPath to find target node
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[text()='content']", document, XPathConstants.NODE);

            // assembles jquery/css selector
            String result = "";
            while (node != null && node.getParentNode() != null) {
                result = readPath(node) + " " + result;
                node = node.getParentNode();
            }
            System.out.println(result);
            // returns html body div#myDiv.foo.bar p#tID 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Gets id and class attributes of this node
    private static String readPath(Node node) {
        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
        String id = readAttribute(attributes.getNamedItem("id"), "#");
        String clazz = readAttribute(attributes.getNamedItem("class"), ".");
        return node.getNodeName() + id + clazz;
    }

    // Read attribute
    private static String readAttribute(Node node, String token) {
        String result = "";
        if(node != null) {
            result = token + node.getTextContent().replace(" ", token);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

---

**XML EXAMPLE**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="myDiv" class="foo bar">
            <p id="tID">content</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**EXPLANATIONS**

1. Object `document` points to evaluated XML.
2. The XPath `//*[text()='content']` finds everthing with text = 'content', and find the node.
3. The `while` loops up to the first node, getting id and classes of current element.

---

**MORE EXPLANATIONS**

1. In this new solution I'm using [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/). So, you can have `<br>`, for example, and cleaner will replace with `<br/>`.
2. To use HtmlCleaner, just download the newest jar [here](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: but it's not a XML Document,if has `<br>` or other tag not has end-tag ,it will can't parse.`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".`

Comment: I edited my answer to work with not well-formed XML. Take a look.